# IBM.XMS.Admin error while connecting to LDAP on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ldap, ibm-mq, xms

I am getting following exception only in windows 8.

XMSAO0121E: An error was returned from the LDAP naming service.
A call has been made to the LDAP naming service which did not complete successfully.
Review the linked exception details for further information on the cause of the problem.

I have same library on windows XP and it works without any problem for same configuration. Please help.

REgards
Pawan

Comment: And the linked exception says...what?  Did you print it?

Comment: Sorry About this.. I found out there is hot fix for Windows 8. I installed it and everything is fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hot fix available for this issue.. you can download from IBM or can ask your IT team to install it. - [hotfix download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2802148)

Comment: Please provide the link to hot fix. Is that a IBM hot fix or Windows. You mention problem is not seen on Windowx XP

Comment: My IT support installed the fix. yes.. v 7.5 of MQ and xms library 2.5.0.2  . The installation did work in xp but not in win8.. they installed the hot fix and it started working.. no code change.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2802148 .. the link to the hotfix.. It is late.. but if anyone interested.